# RESTful implementation of sitewide (multiple models) search with Sunspot Solr Search through a SearchController. Is that correct?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, sunspot

So I am using a SearchController to manage sitewide searches (user queries are full-text searched in two different models), and it works in the rails development server, but it doesn't work on Heroku. I suspect this means I am committing some sort of MVC or RESTful logic error because I think I have had this issue before with heroku and my localhost server where the latter was more lenient with my code. Should I be using a collection or member route of some sort?

**Search Controller:**

```
  def index
    @search = Post.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
    end
    @posts = @search.results
    @search = Group.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
    end
    @groups = @search.results
  end
```

**Route:**

```
resources :search, :only => [:index]
```

**Search form (in HAML):**

```
-form_tag '/search', :method => :get do
        =text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :id => 'searchfield'
        =submit_tag 'search',:name => nil, :id => 'searchbutton'
```

**Heroku Logs from the failed action:**

```
2011-12-16T04:05:20+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=integer" for 
68.6.74.167 at 2011-12-15 20:05:20 -0800
2011-12-16T04:05:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by SearchController#index as HTML
2011-12-16T04:05:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"integer"}
2011-12-16T04:05:23+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-robot-3215.heroku.com/search dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3030ms status=500 bytes=728
2011-12-16T04:05:23+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed   in 3022ms
2011-12-16T04:05:23+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-12-16T04:05:23+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
2011-12-16T04:05:23+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/search_controller.rb:3:in `index'
2011-12-16T04:05:23+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-12-16T04:05:23+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Thanks for your help. Let me know if I should give any more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, the only problem is that your Heroku application can't connect to any Solr host.

If you're using the Websolr addon in Heroku then you should open a support ticket because this should be working. Otherwise, you should run this in the heroku console:

```
Sunspot.config.solr.url
```

If that points to "http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr" or similar then *that's* your problem. You need that to point to some internet-accessible Solr server.

Comment: Ok it pointed to the problematic url. Does this mean I should be using Websolr?

Comment: Or preferably some alternative that is free? I see that websolr costs money. The reason I switched to solr/sunspot in the first place was that it was easier for me to implement compared to Thinking Sphinx and Elastic_Search. maybe I will need to go back to those.

Comment: If you want to go with a free search service for now, you can use your free micro EC2 instance (everybody gets one for free) to host a Solr server and connect to it.

To get it running on EC2:
(make sure you boot the EC2 instance with port 8983 open to the public).


wget http://www.alliedquotes.com/mirrors/apache//lucene/solr/3.5.0/apache-solr-3.5.0.tgz; tar xvzf apache-solr*; cd apache-solr-3.5.0/example; java -jar start.jar

Then, in your Rails initializer somewhere (e.g. config/initializers/sunspot.rb) set Sunspot's config to point to http://whatever-ec2-hostname:8983/solr

Comment: Or you could do the same with ElasticSearch and get easier setup and a more powerful tool : )

Comment: wouldn't I still need to use a server that is connected to ES, which would ostensibly cost money?

Comment: also it doesn't work on heroku, right? My knowledge of servers is pitiful. For example I have no idea how to go about connecting to my free WebSolr EC2 instance. I just figured Elastic SEarch would be easier, but it seems there is no easy solution. I discarded thinking sphinx because I couldn't figure out how to cleanly switch my applicaition to Mysql